# Reshaping image in R

Tags: r, keras, reticulate

I'm doing image recognition with Keras in R. I'm trying to convert my images to single dimensional matrices. Here is my code :

```
pics <- c("p1.jpg", "p2.jpg", "p3.jpg", "p4.jpg", "p5.jpg", "p6.jpg",
          "c1.jpg", "c2.jpg", "c3.jpg", "c4.jpg", "c5.jpg", "c6.jpg") 
mypic <- list()
mypic <- lapply(pics, readImage)
mypic <- lapply(mypic, resize, 28, 28)
mypic <- lapply(mypic, array_reshape, c(28,28,3))
```

The last line leads to the following error message:

Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) : 
Your current architecture is 64bit however this version of Python is compiled for 32bit.

How do I proceed?

Comment: The error message is fairly descriptive. You need to fix your Python installation.

Comment: from the error, try changing your installation from 64bit to 32

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks. So how do I proceed to fix it?

Comment: @AkshitBhalla Reinstall the correct Python (a 32bit installation is, nowadays, virtually always an error).